# Iterate a directory located over a FTP server using Laravel

Tags: laravel, ftp, iteration

I'm trying to look over an FTP server using a Larvel 8 application to see if there are files to download. The structure of folders may vary, so I'm thinking to use an iterative function.

The problem however is at the beginning. When using different methods over Storage class I get stuck because I can only obtain an array of strings and don't know how to proceed with iteration.

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->allDirectories();
```

The output is

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "2020"
  1 => "2021"
]
```

What I have to do is to iterate over those folders, which contain months, to get all files.
Thanks in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First iterate the array which contains string of files and folders names.
2. Then get the url of the folder or file using storage function.
   `Storage::url('iterated_file_or_folder_name')`
3. Use the url and check whether the item is file or folder using inbuilt
   function `is_file` or  `is_dir`
4. Now, if its a file download it or if its a directory append it to the url and
   crawl through that new directory as well.

Thank you